# My question was closed as duplicate

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions

[My question about iOS 11.4 Full Jailbreak](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324516/jailbreak-ios-11-4-full-version?noredirect=1&lq=1) was closed as a duplicate although it was asked 1 month earlier than an “original” question. Can someone investigate this?

Answer (score 1):

When we close as a duplicate it doesn't really matter which question was asked first but which question got the "better"/more helpful answer. I know that the "on hold" reason implies otherwise, but as this site is all about getting good answers the focus is more on the answers than the questions.

If things change (e.g. a jailbreak becomes available) it doesn't matter which of the questions is open or closed. People who want to answer will find the open question easily, and can provide an answer there.

PS: Whether a question about the availability of a specific jailbreak even is on-topic and doesn't qualify for getting closed due to "missing research" or "asking for an external resource" is a different matter...

Comment: Off-topic comments removed, on-topic comments still welcome :-)